# rewrite with partial fraction decomposition

Tags: factoring, partial-fractions

I want to rewrite this statement:

$$f(x)=\frac{x}{-x^2-x+1}$$ into this statement
$$f(x)=\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt5}}{1-(x \cdot \phi)}+\frac{-\frac{1}{\sqrt5}}{1-(x  \cdot (1-\phi))}$$

provided $\phi = \frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$

I tried for 2 days and still can't. I know how to do partial fraction decomposition but at the end I ended up with:

$$\frac{-\frac{1}{\sqrt5}\phi}{(x+\phi)} + \frac{\frac{-1+\sqrt5}{2\sqrt5}}{(-x+\frac{-1+\sqrt5}{2})}$$

which is quite far from the goal.

can anyone solve this?

please give me very detail and step by step demonstration. I'm newbie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac x{-x^2-x+1}=\frac A{1-x\phi}+\frac B{1-x(1-\phi)}=\frac{A-xA+x\phi A+B-x\phi B}{(1-x(1-\phi))(1-x\phi)}$$
$$(1-x(1-\phi))(1-x\phi)=-x^2-x+1$$

Hence $$\phi A-A-\phi B=1$$
$$A+B=0$$

So that $$A=\frac 1{\sqrt5}$$ and $$B=-\frac{1}{\sqrt5}$$

From where you were:

$$\frac{-\frac{1}{\sqrt5}\phi}{(x+\phi)} + \frac{\frac{-1+\sqrt5}{2\sqrt5}}{(-x+\frac{-1+\sqrt5}{2})}=\frac{-\frac{1}{\sqrt5}\phi}{(x+\phi)} + \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt5}(\phi-1)}{-x+(\phi-1)}$$

And keeping in mind that $1/\phi=\phi-1$ we get
$$\frac{-\frac{1}{\sqrt5}}{(\frac x\phi+1)} + \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt5}}{-\frac x{\phi-1}+1}=\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt5}}{1-x  \phi}+\frac{-\frac{1}{\sqrt5}}{1-x  (1-\phi)}$$

Comment: @user3270418 I have added the steps that lead to the final result from where you were...